# Get and remove from linked list results in Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The retrieval of a message from a linked list and then removing that message from the list results in a segmentation fault.

First Message and Server Message struct:

```
// used to store messages.
struct server_message {
    char message[80];
    char id[80];
    struct server_message *next_msg;
};

//head of the list
static struct server_message *first_message = NULL;
```

Get Message function

```
char *get_message(char *id) {
    char *message;
    char *not_found =(char *)  malloc( sizeof(char) * 20 );
    not_found = "No messages available";
    struct server_message *curr_msg = first_message;
    struct server_message *prev_msg = first_message;

    if (curr_msg != NULL && (strcmp(curr_msg->id, id) != 0)) {
        strcpy (message, curr_msg->message);
        //Remove message
        first_message = NULL;
        return message;
    }


    while (curr_msg->next_msg != NULL) {
        curr_msg = curr_msg->next_msg;

        if (strcmp(curr_msg->id, id) != 0) {
            strcpy (message, curr_msg->message);
            //Remove message
            prev_msg->next_msg = curr_msg->next_msg;
            return message;
        } else {
            prev_msg = curr_msg;
        }
    }
    return not_found;
}
```

Updated Code Still seg faulting

```
char *get_message(char *id) {
    char *message = (char *)  malloc( sizeof(char) * 80 );
    char *not_found=(char *)  malloc( sizeof(char) * 20 );
    strcpy(not_found, "No messages available");
    struct server_message *curr_msg = first_message;
    struct server_message *prev_msg = NULL;

    while (curr_msg->next_msg != NULL) {

        if (strcmp(curr_msg->id, id) != 0) {
            strcpy (message, curr_msg->message);
            //Remove message
            if (prev_msg == NULL) {
                first_message = curr_msg->next_msg;
            } else {
                prev_msg->next_msg = curr_msg->next_msg;
            }
            return message;
        } else {
            prev_msg = curr_msg;
            curr_msg = curr_msg->next_msg;
        }
    }
    return not_found;
}
```

Comment: Debugger.......................

Comment: This code is seriously broken.  Memory leaks, dereferences of uninitialized pointers, etc.  Just a couple:  (1) `message` is never initialized, yet you try to store to it.  Segmentation fault.  (2) `not_found` is set to storage from `malloc`.  But before that storage is ever used, `not_found` is immediately set to a constant string.  Memory leak.  I'm sure there's more.  This seem to be more of a problem of not knowing C than finding a bug.

Comment: @TomKarzes For the message can I use  `char message[80]`?

Comment: Only if you don't use it after the function returns.  Remember, that would be on the local stack.  It is unavailable when the function returns.  If you instead use `malloc`, then you must use it for all return values, and caller must free it.  Otherwise it's a memory leak.

Comment: never cast th eresult of malloc()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// used to store messages.
struct server_message {
    char message[80];
    char id[80];
    struct server_message *next_msg;
};

//head of the list
static struct server_message *first_message = NULL;

char *get_message(char *id) {
    struct server_message *curr_msg = first_message;
    struct server_message *prev_msg = NULL;

    while (curr_msg != NULL) {               /* FIX1: iterate until we do not have an item */
        if (strcmp(curr_msg->id, id) == 0) { /* FIX2: 0 is equal */
            //Remove message
            if (prev_msg == NULL) {
                first_message = curr_msg->next_msg;
            } else {
                prev_msg->next_msg = curr_msg->next_msg;
            }
            return strdup(curr_msg->message);
        } else {
            prev_msg = curr_msg;
            curr_msg = curr_msg->next_msg;
        }
    }
    return strdup ("No messages available");
}

struct server_message d = {"foo-4", "4", 0};
struct server_message c = {"foo-3", "3", &d};
struct server_message b = {"foo-2", "2", &c};
struct server_message a = {"foo-1", "1", &b};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char *t;

        first_message = &a;

        t = get_message("1");
        printf ("1: %s\n", t);
        free (t);

        t = get_message("3");
        printf ("3: %s\n", t);
        free (t);

        t = get_message("10");
        printf ("10: %s\n", t);
        free (t);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried updating the code as you mentioned but its still failing. Would you mind taking a look at the updates i posted?

Comment: You have allocated 20 bytes in `not_found` while `"No messages available"` is more than 20 bytes. Also, add a null check for the pointer `first_message`.

Comment: I also saw not that 20 bytes is not enough.. Easiest regarding the not_found return, would be to `return strdup("No messages available");`

But the code has memory-leaks aswell..